# Trying to open a virtual pc file from my windows xp drive, says wrong version

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

On my new windows 7 computer, I just downloaded virtual pc.

Now I am accessing my older computers hard drive where I had virtualPC's on there, and when trying to run the vm it says its the wrong version.

Is my vm file basically garbage now on windows 7? that can't be true!

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry - your VM is fine.

You probably need to create a new VM definition - it seems that the format has changed in Windows Virtual PC, and the old VMC files don't work any more.  However, your VHD file should work as-is - no need to reinstall your OS.  Just create a new virtual machine in Windows Virtual PC, then point it to your existing VHD file.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, as I have VMs around that work fine with newer versions. [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is able to use the Virtual PC files if you'd like to try another option.